# Нет эффекта CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

Tags: c++, cmake, сборка, arm, кросс-компиляция

Cmake не видит `OpenCVConfig.cmake`. Установил `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "$ENV{HOME}/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv-android-shared/sdk/native/jni")`. Файл присутствует

[image: директория OpenCVConfig.cmake]

Хочу использовать OpenCV в приложении QT под андроид. Qt, OpenCV, текущий проект собираются с использованием одного и того же toolchain `../Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`. Так же `ANDROID_PLATFORM=28` `ANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a`.
В `CMakeLists.txt` текущего проекта:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
        "$ENV{HOME}/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv-android-shared/sdk/native/jni")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
        ...
        "$ENV{HOME}/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv-android-shared/sdk/native/jni")
```

Ошибка Cmake:

```
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Подозреваю Cmake ищет определенную версию/платформу OpenCV, но настройки сборки аналогичные.

Comment: При конфигурации проекта cmake добавляйте параметр -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=...

Comment: @こきん Так выглядит строка конфигурации: `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/home/dym/Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake"
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a
-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/home/dym/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv-android-shared/sdk/native/jni`. Нет эффекта

Comment: Предложенное решение с установкой пути до `OpenCVConfig.cmake` в переменную `OpenCV_DIR` работает. Не уверен в его правильности.
(`set(OpenCV_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/.../native/jni")
`)

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` используется **только** для поиска "Find" скриптов.

Для поиска "Config" скриптов используется переменная `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` или `XXX_DIR`.

Это различие переменных можно выявить, прочитав внимательнее сообщение об ошибке:

> By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

> Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

> set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.

В последней фразе имеются ввиду именно файлы `OpenCVConfig.cmake` и `opencv-config.cmake`.

Различие использования переменных `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` и `XXX_DIR` в том, что переменная `XXX_DIR` задаёт путь к "Config" файлу только одного пакета, а переменная `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` может указывать на директорию, куда установленно сразу несколько пакетов.

Между прочим, обе эти переменные - `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` и `XXX_DIR` - можно задавать в окружении (*environment*). Тогда их не надо передавать через параметры `cmake` или устанавливать внутри `CMakeLists.txt` (последнее вообще не рекомедуется).

(А вот задание переменной `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` внутри `CMakeLists.txt` - единственный рекомендованный вариант).